# Current through a transistor

Tags: transistors, current, npn, pnp

I have a problem related with a transistor circuit. Please tell me whether my approach is correct or not.

[image]

I need to find the current through the 94.6ohms transistor.

My approach (Assuming PN voltage is 0.6V)

1. Since the NPN transitor has 5.6V between the base and emitter,
   it will be biased.
   So, the voltage at the base of NPN will be 0.6V with respect to ground.
2. So, current through 1K resistors will be (15V-0.2V)/2kohms = 7.4mA. (Vce = 0.2V)
3. Since the voltage at the top of 1k emitter resistor is at 0.6V, , the PNP transistor now, will turn as, the voltage between the base and the emitter is greater than 0.6V (As 15V-0.6V > 0.6V)
4. So,Current through the 94.6ohms is (15V-0.2V)/94.6Ohms = 156mA.

Is my calculation right?

Comment: The circuit is interesting because the PNP emitter is at the same voltage as the NPN base, idealistically speaking. (It is also the basis for a practical circuit, though this isn't a good example of one.) This would imply about 100 mA in the resistor you mentioned (99 mA would be closer.)

Comment: Could you explain your 100mA calculation ?

Comment: And the voltage at the base of NPN is 0.6V and PNP is also 0.6V with respect to ground, right ?

Comment: No. I see 5.6 V at the base of the NPN, relative to the wire at the bottom of the image, which is also what I'm assuming the 15 V supply rail is also relative to.

Comment: No. I don't think so. When the NPN has more than 0.6V drop, the transistor will turn ON, right. So , it will drop only the required Vbe , right?

Comment: No. I don't think you are correct. The NPN emitter will "follow" its base. So the NPN emitter will be 5.0 V.

Comment: Ok. Could you please explain how the calculation of Current through 1k and 94.6ohms?

Comment: If you decide to agree with me about the NPN emitter voltage (and that's still up in the air), then it follows that there will be 5 mA of NPN emitter current. That current will also cause a 5 V drop across the NPN collector resistor. (Not important, just a detail.) The PNP base will be at 5.0 V, so its emitter will be at 5.6 V, as the PNP emitter follows its base.

Comment: This is actually a practical circuit topology that has been used in times past to increase the current compliance of an output, without significantly changing its voltage. I've seen it in books from time to time, too. You can find this in the early chapters of the 2nd and 3rd editions of The Art of Electronics.

Comment: I'm sorry. You totally lost me. Even if we agree on NPN emitter voltage, NPN emitter current  would be , (15-5)/2000 =5mA. If the 5V drops at emitter resistor, then 10V should drop across the collector resistor, right?

Comment: The collector current approximately equals the emitter current. So the *voltage drop* is 5 V. However, yes, the collector voltage of the NPN would be 10 V. So a 5 V drop does mean 10 V at the NPN collector. But I think you are not really seeing these two facts at the same time.

Comment: You talk about voltage relative to ground,  but you haven't designated which node in your circuit is ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example circuit we have this situation:

Assuming \$V_{BE} = 0.6V\$ and \$I_C = I_E\$

[image]

Do you have any questions?

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: Thank you for your *help*!